# What are the different ways of implementing Docker FROM?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Inheritance of an image is normally done using docker's from command, for example.

```
from centos7:centos7
```

In my case, I have a Dockerfile which I want to use as a base image builder, and I have two sub dockerfiles which customize that file.

I *do not* want to commit the original dockerfile as a container to dockerhub, so for example, I  would like to do:

```
Dockerfile
slave/Dockerfile
master/Dockerfile
```

Where slave/Dockerfile looks something like this:

```
from ../Dockerfile
```

Is this (or anything similar) possible ?  Or do I have to actually convert the top level Dockerfile to a container, and commit it as  a dockerhub image, before I can leverage it using the docker *FROM* directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *don't have to push your images to dockerhub* to be able to use them as base images. But you need to *build them locally* so that they are stored in your local docker repository. You can not use an image as a base image based on a relative path such as `../Dockerfile`- you must base your own images on other image files that exists in your local repository.

Let's say that your base image uses the following (in the `Dockerfile`):

```
FROM        centos7:centos7
// More stuff...
```

And when you build it you use the following:

```
docker build -t my/base .
```

What happens here is that the image `centos7:centos7` is downloaded from dockerhub. Then your image `my/base` is built and stored (without versioning) in your local repository. You can also provide versioning to your docker container by simply providing version information like this:

```
docker build -t my/base:2.0 .
```

When an image has been built as in the example above it can then be used as a `FROM`-image to build other sub-images, at least on the same machine (the same local repository). So, in your sub-image you can use the following:

```
FROM        my/base
```

Basically you don't have to push anything anywhere. All images lives locally on your machine. However, if you attempt to build your sub-image without a previously built base image you get an error.

For more information about building and tagging, check out the docs:

- [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#build)
- [docker tag](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#tag)
- [create your own image](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerimages/#creating-our-own-images)